# Multiple release configurations in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm trying to build two separate applications for release. One of them should have less features than the other. I would disable those features with macros. Something in the lines of:

```
#ifdef DEMO_VERSION
    // less code
#else
    // more code
#endif
```

The question is, how do i define the DEMO_VERSION (which i would usually just put under "other preprocessor macros") so that i could easily switch it on and off? I could just define it manually every time i need to compile the app and delete it when compiling the actual release version, but i suspect there could be a smarter way of achieving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manage build configurations from the project info view in Xcode. Here, you can duplicate the default "Release" configuration, and then adjust the build settings to define a specific preprocessor macro for each configuration:

1. Select your project from the project navigator pane on the left. In the projects/targets list that is shown, ensure you have the project selected.
2. Choose the **Info** tab. Under **Configurations**, click **+ > Duplicate "Release" Configuration** and rename it something like "Release (Demo)".
3. Choose the **Build Settings** tab. Expand the **Preprocessor Macros** entry to show the per-configuration settings. Add `DEMO_VERSION=1` for the "Release (Demo)" configuration only.

Now, at compile time, your preprocessor statements will conditionally compile based on your current build configuration.

Comment: WOW! That's cool. I thought there could only be 2 configurations. Another thing to mention: you can also duplicate a scheme and make it use the new configuration. That way it's easy to switch between release/debug/demo builds. Thanks for the help!